# Is there any way to get web URL, author name and other details of web page while copying content (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, copy-paste

I'm stuck in one place and I need help. As I mention in my Question title I want to grab web URL and other details of the same page when we copy any content from web page.

So, scenario would like this : we copying any text from xyz.com page and pasting it in our app at that time we need additional information to paste in app i.e. web URL, author , date time etc. (all accessible fields if possible).

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible. Since you are going to copy that data from the web browser, which is a regular application developed by somebody, you have to be sure that that application supports such functionality. There is nothing for Android system, or Android SDK to provide you the URL and other data from the web page. You even can't determine if the data is copied from web page, or any let's say text file.

Comment: Thanks Vlad Matvienko, 
I'm also looking for iOS answer.. I know it would be the same as Android but still for make sure.. :)

Comment: not sure for iOS, my answer is for Android. But iOS has the custom web browser apps as well (google chrome, firefox, etc.), so I think it is the same.